# track jquery draggable dropped

Tags: jquery, draggable, droppable

I am new to web programming let alone javascript and jquery. But I need to create a set of draggables and droppables (say 10 items in each) and be able to identify and store the position of which draggable is dropped in which droppable.

Say I id all draggable with (drag1, drag2, drag3... drag10) and,
droppable with ids (drop1, drop2, drop3... drop10).

Say users drop drag1 onto drop2, drag2 onto drop3, drag3 onto drop4...drag10 on drop1.

I need to store pair of "drag1:drop2", "drag2:drop3", "drag3:drop4"..."drag10:drop1" into database.

Comment: Take a look at: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp

Comment: @Mordalthunder don't link to w3schools. They're evil.
Dhimant Patel what exactly do you need help with? Javscript syntax to create arrays / objects? Persisting storage through multiple requests?...

Comment: I can use jQuery draggable/droppable (http://jqueryui.com/droppable/) and create a page with items for drag/drop. I only need help with how to identify which "drag" element is dropped on which "drop" element, hence the pair "drag2:drop3". I could imagine I need to use EVENT as shown on the (http://jqueryui.com/droppable/) page when text of droppable changes to "dropped", but couldn't go further.

Comment: To clarify further, I want to be able to make drag-drop pair like ("drag1:drop2") and save it to database. I can take care of db saving part, but just dont know how to collect the drag-drop pairs. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In this JSFiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/qN8s9/1/ 
you have a snippet of code that gets the jQuery object of both dragged and dropped elements.
The key is the the drop event handler function:

```
drop: function(event, ui) {
    alert( $(this).html() );
    alert( $(ui.draggable).html()  );  
}
```

You neeed to trigger some additional logic when the drop event occurs, to store that information on your DB.

Hope that helps!